# Rank of commutative free monoid and Krull dimension of Monoid ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, monoid, krull-dimension

We just introduced the notion of the Krull dimension of a ring in class and I was thinking about the following:

Let A be a commutative, noetherian ring with unit and let $n=\text{dim}(A)$ be the Krull dimension. Furthermore, let $M$ be a free, commutative monoid. Are there any circumstances under which the following holds?
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{dim}(A[M])=\text{dim}(A) + \text{rk}(M)
\end{align*}
Maybe if we assume $M$ to be finitely generated and torsion-free?
I have tried looking for something similar but I have not found anything yet.
If this is never true I would be glad if anyone could provide some counter-examples.

Comment: This is true if you assume M to be an affine monoid. For a proof you may see Theorem 4.3 in Polytopes, Rings and K-theory by Gubeladze, Bruns